# Install FontAwesome via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, font-awesome

I want to integrate [**FontAwesome**](https://fontawesome.com) in my project. I followed [**this Medium's tutorial**](https://medium.com/@umairhassanbaig/ios-how-to-use-font-awesome-in-xcode-project-b8ef255973a3) on how to use it. It is mentioned that **we need to copy fontawesome-webfont.ttf** file in the project. This would be the manual way of integrating it. I have seen different libraries on **GitHub** which are based on **FontAwesome** and can be installed via **Cocoapods** but can this *direct library* be installed via **Cocoapods** or manual is the only option here?

Comment: Hello, Try to search FONTAWESOME on https://cocoapods.org/, i found **pod 'FontAwesome'** from that link. **Link :** https://cocoapods.org/pods/FontAwesome

Comment: @HardikThakkar : Like I said, there many of these libraries. But my question is not around them.